# Radiobutton value to mysql without submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm by no means a javascript programmer so it would be nice if somebody could help me out with this. If have multiple of these ratingsections like in the example down below that are on the same page.

Now I need to send the value of the radiobutton that has been clicked to my database without a submit button and preferably without a refresh.

```
<body>
    <section class="rating">
        <input type="radio" class="radio twenty" name="progress" value="twenty" id="twenty" <?php if($num === 1) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
        <label for="twenty" class="label">1</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio fourty" name="progress" value="fourty" id="fourty" <?php if($num === 2) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
        <label for="fourty" class="label">2</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio sixty" name="progress" value="sixty" id="sixty" <?php if($num === 3) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
        <label for="sixty" class="label">3</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio eighty" name="progress" value="eighty" id="eighty"<?php if($num === 4) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
        <label for="eighty" class="label">4</label>

        <input type="radio" class="radio onehundred" name="progress" value="onehundred" id="onehundred" <?php if($num === 5) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
        <label for="onehundred" class="label">5</label>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

I've already set up the retrieval of checked radiobutton so that it corresponds with a rating of 1 to 5, so I'm currently using testdata to show a 1 to 5 rating.

I don't necessarily need all the details, an overview of steps that need to be done would already be really helful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ZzmxK/)

Add it to the head after the jQuery include
And I changed the class to id of the progress bar

```
$(function() { // when document has loaded
  $(".radio").on("click",function() { // all radios with class="radio ..." 
    // ajax get or post someserver.php?value=twenty/fourty...
    $.get("someserver.php", {value:this.value},function(data) { 
      // add the returned value to a container
      $("#progress-bar").append("Updated "+ data); 
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I wanted to say 'do it on change' but then realised that everythng then fires

Comment: So if there was a `<a href="example.com" class="radio">...</a>`, wouldnt this send `example.com` or `null` to `someserver.php` ?

Comment: Yes, you either need to not give the class radio to other items OR add input[type=radio] or input[name=progress] to the selector

Comment: Thanks alot I've changed this around a bit to work with a laravel controller but it works like a charm. Again thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX for it. If you are using Jquery there are click handlers available which detects your element clicks and initiates a function call that in turn can call an AJAX function to interact with your server side code and send the values to insert in the database.

Comment: A little bit more detailed would be helpful haha. I'm currently downloading the javascript and ajax tutorial from lynda.com already. I don't have the knowledge to currently even know wich exact steps to take.

Answer (score 2):

- add onclick or onchange action to inputs sending ajax request with proper parameter
- recive request, validate data
- insert/update row